# Using Status Description on HttpUnauthorizedResult

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my MVC Application I call the HttpUnauthorizedResult class and specify the statusDescription parameter.

```
if (!canAdd) {
    return new HttpUnauthorizedResult("You do not have access to add");
}
```

This redirects me too the Login method on the AccountController and I then redirect them to the appropriate screen.

```
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
{
if (WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    return RedirectToAction("AccessDenied");
}
    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    return View();
}
```

My question is how do I take advantage of the Status Descripton parameter, it would be nice to display these details in the AccessDenied view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the same issue.
I used the TempData to set a message, because it is not possible to set a Viewbag.

```
filterContext.Controller.TempData["message"] = "Access Denied";
filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
```

The HttpUnauthorizedResult redirects me to the login action of my account Controller where i check for (error)messages:

```
if (TempData.Count > 0)
{
    var message = TempData["message"];
    ModelState.AddModelError("", message.ToString());
}
```